# How to enable Access-Control-Allow-Headers from node js to asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-mvc

I'm using node js to read/process geojson files and asp.net MVC for viewing maps but I'm getting this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://company.com/api/v1/file?id=1&d=1661924420' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Node JS code

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()

app.get(`/api/v1/file`, cors(), (req, res, next) => {
const { id } = req.query
console.log(`Request Params id: ${id}`);
pathFile = `./files/uploads/${id}.geojson`;
readFile(pathFile,'utf8', (err, jsonmap) =>{
    console.log(`Reading File: ${pathFile}`);
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(404).send('No such file found!');
    }else{
        var g = JSON.parse(jsonmap);
        return res.status(200).json(g);
    }
})
})
```

View code in ASP.NET MVC

```
<p id="result">Checking..</p>
<script>
$(function () {
    TestFunction();
});

function TestFunction() {
    var url = "@Url.Content("https://company.com/api/v1/file")";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        type: "GET", /* or type:"GET" or type:"PUT" */
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            id: 1,
            d: Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#result").html("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#result").html("error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Also i'm using ARR to access my node js app. here is my webconfig

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>                 
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:6001/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:6001/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
   <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <clear />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" />
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making the HTTP call from your ASP .NET page to the NodeJS API. Your NodeJS application needs to allow the cors request from the domain where ASP .NET page is hosted/running. You can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to allow the requests.

Steps:

- Install the the `cors` package in the root folder of your NodeJS project.

> npm install cors

- In your code add these lines:

  ```
  import cors from 'cors';
  .
  .
  app.use(cors());
  ```

You can follow the doc to allow custom origins and methods for restricted access.